# Customers Recieving Error Code on Renewal

Tags: authorize.net

When customers try to renew their membership through our normal form, they recieve this:

"Payment Processor Error message: 1: 103 This transaction cannot be accepted."

Not sure what this means or how to fix it, but many of our customers can't renew their memberships because of this.

I wonder if this has anything to do with the technical updates that Auth.net did in mid-August?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Andrew. you say this occurs when the 'renew' - does it work fine for a new membership?

Comment: New memberships work just fine, yep!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an Auth.net password issue. Check this out from their support page on the 103 error:

> This error is generated when your Authorize.Net account is in
>   Password-Required Mode and you are not sending a valid Transaction Key
>   or hash fingerprint with your transaction request.

https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DA852

Answer (score 0):

It happened when authorized account in password required mode.

https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A852

To fix this issue remove the password protected mode in authorized. net account. Below I have mentioned the steps to turn off password protected mode.

To turn Password-Required Mode off:

Click Settings under Account in the main left side menu.Click Password-Required Mode under Security Settings.Uncheck the box next to Require Password for ALL Transactions.Click Submit.